# Embed html in html?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am building a web app in Google Apps Script for the maker space that I run at an ES and it is slowly getting longer and more complicated. I don't have much HTML training, but in OOP I can manage complexity by creating functions and classes rather than just generating a single giant script. Is there something similar in HTML? I way to write multiple HTML files and then call them individually?

For example, I would like to add this [sticky note](https://codepen.io/thormeier/pen/JjXmppX), but when I pile the CSS and the HTML into my current code, it adds a lot of lines. Is there a way to save this code in a separate file and then call it within a  in the main body? I have tried saving it as a separate HTML file (called `stickyNote` and using `<?!= include('stickyNote'); ?>` but this doesn't work.

EDIT: Here is a simplified version of my code. It has several components (I am using Google Apps Script), but it is as simple as I could recreate the issue. The actual program has another CSS style sheet for the main HTML and a JavaScript file as well, but neither are needed for the example:

The main code (Code.gs):

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('template');
  return htmlOutput.evaluate().setTitle('Sample');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}
```

The main html script (called 'template'):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width:80%; background-color: green;">
      <p style="font-size: 36px;">all of the things</p>
    </div>

    <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: gray;">
      <?!= include('stickyNote'); ?>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The style for the stickyNote sheet (called StickyStyle):

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&display=swap');

/* Some positioning and ratios */
.sticky-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-outer {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 92.5925926%;
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

/* Shadow behind the sticky note */
.sticky:before {
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  content: '';
  width: 90%;
  left: 5px;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}

/* The sticky note itself */
.sticky-content {
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(187, 235, 255, 1) 0%,
    rgba(187, 235, 255, 1) 12%,
    rgba(170, 220, 241, 1) 75%,
    rgba(195, 229, 244, 1) 100%
  );
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
  font-size: 1.25rem;

  clip-path: url(#stickyClip);
}


/* Position the sticky nicely, so it looks better */
.sticky-note {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container-inner {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 25px;
}

/* Add responsiveness */
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .sticky-content {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .container-inner {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sticky-content {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .container-inner {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .sticky-content {
    font-size: 1.875rem;
  }
  .container-inner {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
</style>
```

And the stickyNote HTML sheet:

```
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= include('StickyStyle'); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <div class="sticky-container">
        <div class="sticky-outer">
          <div class="sticky">
            <svg width="0" height="0">
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="stickyClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                  <path d="M 0 0 Q 0 0.69, 0.03 0.96 0.03 0.96, 1 0.96 Q 0.96 0.69, 0.96 0 0.96 0, 0 0"
                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="square" />
                </clipPath>
              </defs>
            </svg>
            <div class="sticky-content">
              Hello! I'm a<br>
            sticky note!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is what I see:
[image: Web App View]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your `include()` function.

Comment: @Diego edited and added.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, there's still not enough information here to reproduce your problem. Referencing the HTML & CSS using `include()` works just fine. I suggest you try eliminating code and coming up with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to share here.

Comment: @Diego, Okay, I'll do that and change the post.

Comment: If the code is javascript, html or css then you can save them in html project files and include them in your code with `<?!= include('filename'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Update the `include()` method to evaluate the HTML content.

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
```

The evaluation that happens in the `doGet()` will not correctly evaluate the nested HTML because it's already been included as [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) (i.e. the "<?!= include('StickyStyle'); ?>" will not be evaluated and will instead appear as a string). So you need to evaluate the nested elements individually as you're building the final template file.

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

I have replicated your setup and did some trial & error tests. It seems that the ***StickyStyle*** (css/style sheet file) will only take effect inside of a main html file (***template.html***).

What worked on my end was I have added the scriptlet `<?!= include('StickyStyle'); ?>` inside the ***template.html***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= include('StickyStyle'); ?>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width:80%; background-color: green;">
      <p style="font-size: 36px;">all of the things</p>
    </div>

    <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: gray;">
      <?!= include('stickyNote'); ?>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And removed that scriptlet in the ***stickyNote.html***:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <div class="sticky-container">
        <div class="sticky-outer">
          <div class="sticky">
            <svg width="0" height="0">
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="stickyClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                  <path d="M 0 0 Q 0 0.69, 0.03 0.96 0.03 0.96, 1 0.96 Q 0.96 0.69, 0.96 0 0.96 0, 0 0"
                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="square" />
                </clipPath>
              </defs>
            </svg>
            <div class="sticky-content">
              Hello! I'm a<br>
            sticky note!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Sample result

> [image]

## Resources:

- I have followed the same structure as per the Apps Script sample about [Separate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript)